# Serialize Two Sequential Transactions in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

**TL;DR version:**

I have two transactions in a MySQL stored procedure. The second one depends on the data inserted by the first one. I'm using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` and `COMMIT AND CHAIN` at the end of the first transaction, but the second transaction does not appear to see the first's data.

If I run the same query that is in the second transaction afterwards, it does what I expect. So I think I need to have the second transaction truly wait for the first one to be finished.

**Details:**

I have a stored procedure in MySQL 5.6 that essentially creates an entry in a table that lists some items, then creates a copy of data that relates to the parent item. That data is then joined to another table that does not change.

In this example:

r_subject -1:N-> put_test_join -1:1-> put_test_data

put_test_bundles also has a relation with put_test_join, essentially to identify the name of the test bundle for the given data. I'm not particularly concerned about the structure of the database, but rather an issue I'm having with a procedure:

```
create procedure create_branch(IN _branch_name varchar(255), IN _project varchar(255),
                                                       IN _subver varchar(255), IN _revision int(10),
                                                       IN _parent varchar(255), IN _owner varchar(255))
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE parent_id INT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE new_tbid INT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE _rid INT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE _pgid INT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE _pdid INT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE _dupe_id INT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE _rfu_id INT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE ptj_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT rid,pgid,pdid,dupe_id,rfu_id FROM put_test_join WHERE tbid = parent_id;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  DECLARE exit handler for SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
      @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET @full_error = CONCAT('ERROR ', @errno, ' (', @sqlstate, '): ', @text);
    SELECT @full_error;
  END;

  IF (SELECT COALESCE(id) FROM put_test_bundles WHERE put_test_bundles.name = _branch_name AND project = _project AND subver = _subver LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This branch already exists';
  END IF; # Check for dupes

  SELECT id INTO parent_id FROM put_test_bundles WHERE name = _parent AND project = _project AND subver = _subver;

  IF (parent_id IS NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Parent not found';
  END IF;

  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

  OPEN ptj_cursor;
  START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO put_test_bundles (name, project, subver, revision, parent, owner, istest, locked) VALUES (_branch_name, _project, _subver, _revision, parent_id, _owner, 0, 0);
    SET new_tbid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ptd_loop: LOOP
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE ptd_loop;
      END IF;
      FETCH NEXT FROM ptj_cursor INTO _rid, _pgid, _pdid, _dupe_id, _rfu_id;
      INSERT INTO put_test_data (location_override, bit_override, test_name, pe_description, trimtest, tr_skip, td_skip, tbd, test_in, test_out, test_out_p2, test_out_p3, test_out_p4, mask_blow, high, low, step, default_setting, operating_value, mask_address, mask_row, iteration, username, updatedBy) SELECT location_override, bit_override, test_name, pe_description, trimtest, tr_skip, td_skip, tbd, test_in, test_out, test_out_p2, test_out_p3, test_out_p4, mask_blow, high, low, step, default_setting, operating_value, mask_address, mask_row, iteration, username, updatedBy FROM put_test_data WHERE id = _pdid;
      INSERT INTO put_test_join (rid, tbid, pgid, pdid, dupe_id, rfu_id) VALUES (_rid, new_tbid, _pgid, LAST_INSERT_ID(), _dupe_id, _rfu_id);
    END LOOP;
  COMMIT AND CHAIN;
  CLOSE ptj_cursor;
    UPDATE put_test_data JOIN
    (SELECT parent.id as parent_id,dupe.id as dupe_id FROM
    (SELECT t.name,r.project,r.location,r.location_bit,d.id
        FROM put_test_data d
            JOIN put_test_join ptj on d.id = ptj.pdid
            JOIN r_subject r ON ptj.rid = r.rid
            JOIN put_test_bundles t ON ptj.tbid = t.id
        WHERE t.name = _branch_name and r.project = _project FOR UPDATE) parent
    JOIN
    (SELECT t.name,p.project,p.location,p.location_bit,p.functionality,d.id,d.dupe_parent,d.dupe_diverged
        FROM put_test_data d
            JOIN put_test_join ptj on d.id = ptj.pdid
            JOIN duplicates p ON ptj.dupe_id = p.rid
            JOIN put_test_bundles t ON ptj.tbid = t.id
        WHERE t.name = _branch_name and p.project = _project) dupe
                                                    ON parent.name                  = dupe.name
                                                    AND parent.project              = dupe.project
                                                    AND parent.location        = dupe.location
                                                    AND parent.location_bit    = dupe.location_bit
    WHERE parent.project = _project
      AND parent.name = _branch_name) s ON put_test_data.id = s.dupe_id
    SET put_test_data.dupe_parent = s.parent_id WHERE put_test_data.dupe_parent IS NULL AND s.parent_id IS NOT NULL;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Essentially this creates the entry in put_test_bundles, then makes copies all the related parent data and relates them to the new test bundle and existing r_subject.

That transaction works just fine, but after that is complete, I need to look through the data for the ids of data that has a duplicate functionality and "link" them together. This fails I think because the second transaction can't see the data from the first transaction. I'm using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` and `COMMIT AND CHAIN` at the end of the first transaction, but the second transaction does not appear to work. If I run the exact same query that is in the second transaction, it does what I expect. So I think I need to have the second transaction truly wait for the first one to be finished.

**Update:** I am calling this stored procedure from sails.js application. Even when I encapsulated the second query into another stored procedure and called them like so:

```
let result = await sails.sendNativeQuery('CALL create_branch($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);', [branch, project, subver, 0, parent, user]);
let linkCount = await sails.sendNativeQuery('CALL link_dupes($1, $2);', [project, branch]);
```

The second procedure *still* doesn't see the data from the first one. How can I guarantee that the first procedure is completely committed and the data is available for read before I run the second query?

Comment: Why do you have two transactions instead of just one?

Comment: The second transaction depends on the data from the first transaction. Since the parent data and duplicate data is side by side in the same table, the ids of the parents is different for each run

Comment: That an sql statement depends on the results of the previous sql statement does not mean that they have to be in separate transactions. Actually, it usually means the opposite: you want the dependent statements in the same transaction.

Comment: Originally, I had the second query as part of one transaction (after the `END LOOP` and `CLOSE ptj_cursor` statements) and that didn't work either. I incorrectly assumed that the first transaction would have to be committed first. From there I tried `  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` and `COMMIT AND CHAIN` but the second query still doesn't see the rows inserted by the first.

Comment: Since I'm calling this from a sails.js application, I tried separating the second query into another procedure and calling them synchronously with await. The second query *still* doesn't see the data.

Comment: I don't think this is a transaction issue. You said originally the two parts were in a single transaction and yet it did not work. Commit return when all modifications are persisted, so the 2nd transaction should see the 1st transaction's changes. Isolation levels are there to control concurrent transactions. Since your transactions are not concurrent, the isolation level does not affect their behaviour.

Comment: Solved it by moving the second query into another stored procedure and calling it via node. Not sure why it wasn't working in pure SQL, but this workaround will do. Thanks!